# Why doesn't my math add up in my LCG?

Tags: java, lcg

For example here: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Winter2009/Luo/Linear%20Congruential%20Generator/linear%20congruential%20gen1.html

I am trying to implement an LCG for an example problem set, but it's not working for me and I cant seem to figure out why?

The equation is straight forward: Xn+1 =(aXn + c) mod m

From the reference above:
For example, the sequence obtained when X0 = a = c = 7, m = 10, is
7, 6, 9, 0, 7, 6, 9, 0, ...

Implementing this in java, for example -

```
public static void lcg(){

    int a = 7;
    int c = 7;
    int m = 10;
    int x0 = 7;
    int N = 10;

    for (int x = x0; x < x0+N; x++){

        int result = (a*x + c) % m;

        System.out.println(result);

    }
```

I get the output:
6
3
0
7
4
1
8
5
2
9

Rather than the expected 7,6,9,0,...

I get the same on paper. Can anyone figure out what is going wrong?

Similarly, a=10, c=7, m=11, x0 = 3 should give a repeating pattern of 4,3,4,3 but I get 
4
3
2
1
0
10
9
8
7
6

Comment: "I get the same on paper". Do you mean when done on paper you get the same results as the program, or as the expected answer?

Comment: And this looks like it's supposed to be iteration. Isn't `x` supposed to become whatever the last iteration `result` was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to just be a misunderstanding of iteration. It doesn't appear to be a problem with the equation, but what you do with the result of the equation.

I read `Xn+1 = (aXn + c) mod m` as

> The next value of x will be the ***current value of `x`***, plus `c`, mod `m`".

Note my emphasis. You're throwing away the current value of `x` (`result`), then just using the "iteration counter variable" in the equation in the next iteration.

Change the loop to

```
for (int x = x0, i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // Note x is being updated instead
    x = (a*x + c) % m;

    System.out.print(x);
}

69076
```

Comment: Or use something like `for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)` and initialise `x` to `x0` before the loop.

Comment: @msandiford Updated

Comment: Thank you. Yes, clearly I misunderstood the formula because I was applying a function to a series rather than iterating on the result.

Comment: @BrianJackson No problem. I like to try to say equations out loud when I need to make sense of them or debug a problem. It often sheds light on misunderstandings.